# What is the use of custom directives in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm newer to angularjs, it's difficult to understand the custom directive examples and the releated blogs.

why we use it and what is the usage of custom directives.(Using the built in directives is easy to understand and use)

It's possible to write our own custom directives based on our needs ?

what is the need of custom directives in angular js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reusablity of code..... You can reuse your code at any Pages and anywhere in your projects.

solve the complex operations in this easily.

Reduce the amount of your code.Call it anywhere.

Handle your Dom easily.

Answer (score 6):

Directives could be used to increment the reusability of code.

Directives infact could be used to split the code of a complex app into more simple parts, reusable in others pages or projects.

Directives could be used to save the two way data binding, when AngularJS is used in conjunction with third party plugin.

Generally directives are used for DOM manipulation

Angular’s philosophy is modular development allowing us to write our front-end code with directives

I hope will helps you

Answer (score 2):

Custom directives gives you the chance to define your own "web components", a very simple example would be a customize menu for your application, using custom directives you could write it once and use it in several applications.

Read more about it and you'll find it very useful (but completely optional as you might have enough with built in ones).

As an example, I find this [link](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html) quite useful.

Comment: Thanks pedro...i Need to study lot about this....